# AttributeError: module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'Dataset'

Tags: python, lightgbm

I have installed lightgbm via `conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm` and imported `import lightgbm as lgb` successfully, but when I try `train.lgm` I get this error: AttributeError: module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'Dataset' . 
I also imported `from sklearn import *`. I updated scikit-learn but didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As an somehow unrelated advice, check out [Why using import * is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Comment: Why do you expect `train.lgm` to work at all? Did you probably mean `lgb.train()`? If so, we will need to see how to you call this function, as it seems there is something wrong in the parameter names that you provide